# How do i know the size of the small images the border and the way they look like?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code in the html:

```
<div id="thumbs-wrapper">
        <div id="thumbs">
            <a href="#pixar" class="selected"><img src="img/small/pixar.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#bugs"><img src="img/small/bugs.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#cars"><img src="img/small/cars.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <a id="prev" href="#"></a>
        <a id="next" href="#"></a>
    </div>
```

And the css code:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: url(img/gui/bg_glare.png) top center no-repeat #bcc;
}
html > body {
    min-height: 600px;
}
body * {
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 22px;
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 50px;
}
#carousel-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#carousel, #thumbs {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#carousel-wrapper .caroufredsel_wrapper {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #899;
}

#carousel span, #carousel img,
#thumbs a, #thumbs img  {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#carousel span, #carousel a,
#thumbs span, #thumbs a {
    position: relative;
}
#carousel img,
#thumbs img {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#carousel img.glare,
#thumbs img.glare {
    width: 102%;
    height: auto;
}

#carousel span {
    width: 554px;
    height: 313px;
}

#thumbs-wrapper {
    padding: 20px 40px;
    position: relative;
}
#thumbs a {
    border: 2px solid #899;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-transition: border-color .5s;
    -moz-transition: border-color .5s;
    -ms-transition: border-color .5s;
    transition: border-color .5s;
}
#thumbs a:hover, #thumbs a.selected {
    border-color: #566;
}

#wrapper img#shadow {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#prev, #next {
    background: transparent url('img/gui/carousel_nav.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    display: block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
#prev {
    background-position: 0 0;
    left: 10px;
}
#next {
    background-position: -19px 0;
    right: 10px;
}           
#prev:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -20px;               
}
#next:hover {
    background-position: -19px -20px;               
}
#prev.disabled, #next.disabled {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The result the small images look like this:

[small images](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/28/)

In the link the small images under the big image.

Now i have another images from another jquery with css code and i wanted to change the images frames borders to be the same size and look like the css of the small images.

What part of the small images css code i need ? What is setting the size height width and shape of the small images ?

Comment: This is a screenshot if the images the ones on the bottom under the big image are those i added to my question the css code. And the images on the left the 3 images on the left this images i want to change to look like those in the bottom. To change the frame,border,height,width http://postimg.org/image/6vn3qkpjx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make edit of your post and add the jQuery plugins that you use.

I also suggest you to use http://bxslider.com/ which has all opportunities and also docs for using it.

Its also mobile optimized.